# Number of idempotent functions $F: \{1,2,3,4,5\} \to \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Tags: combinatorics

**PROBLEM**:

Find the number of functions $F: \{1,2,3,4,5\} \to \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that
$F(F(x))=F(x)$.

My approach:

I tried to approach in a logical manner

But for small cases

$F: \{1,2\} \to \{1,2\} = 4$ (no of such functions)

$F: \{1,2,3\} \to \{1,2,3\} = 13$ ( no of such functions)

I think via combinatorics we might get the answer

I wasn't able to do it
Can you please help me.

Answer is $196$

Comment: What are the four idempotent functions for $\{1,2\}$? (I only count three.)

Comment: @Arthur Every $f$ other than the transposition is idempotent.

Comment: $1\mapsto1, 2\mapsto2; 1\mapsto1, 2\mapsto1; 1\mapsto2, 2\mapsto2$

Comment: A lower bound is the number of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$: For any subset $D\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we can construct a function $F$ which acts as the identity on $D$ and maps everything else to an element of $D$ (actually there should be a large number of such $F$s, provided $D$ is not a singleton).

Comment: I thought of domain of F on x axis and Range on y axis.  Then constructed y=x as reference now , I divided the solution as we say a point is displaced from its position if it doesn't less on y= x line.

Comment: I divided the solution as we say a point is displaced from its reference position if it doesn't lies on y= x line. Then I calculated LOGICALLY for No of displaced points = 0,1,2,3,4 and GOT THE ANSWER .  But I wanted to generalise it but facing unable to imagine the situation        Can you please help